# Eloquent get by related table count

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I created messenger for laravel. Now I wanna list all threads in which user is participating with a count of messages in each thread. I need the count to `where` clause because I want to show only these threads, in which are messages.

My current query:

`$threads = Participant::with('thread.messages') -> where('user_id', Auth::user() -> id) -> get();`

Participant:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this -> hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
}
public function thread()
{
    return $this -> hasOne(Thread::class, 'id', 'thread_id');
}
```

Thread:

```
public function participants()
{
    return $this -> hasMany(Participant::class, 'thread_id', 'id');
}
function messages()
{
    return $this -> hasMany(Message::class, 'thread_id', 'id');
}
```

Message:

```
function user()
{
    return $this -> belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you add your models in question?

Comment: Okay, give me second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `has` for `messages` relation to check thread has message. After that you need to filter the participants relationship using 
`whereHas` And at last use `withCount`for counting message in thread.

```
$threads = Thread::has('messages')
                    ->whereHas('participants', function($query){
                        return $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
                    })->withCount('messages')->get();
```

> Print data

```
foreach($threads as $thread){
    dd($thread->messages_count);
}
```

**Note:** Your relation name `thread` in `Participant` model should be `belongsTo` instead `hasOne`.

Comment: Okay, thanks, it works, but I had to fix one thing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `withCount` for the thread messages. :

```
$threads = Participant::withCount(['thread.messages as message_count'])
                      ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
                      ->having('message_count', '>', 0)
                      ->get();
```